# Django models.py OneToOneField --- help creating a relationship between two models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am having trouble testing a relationship between two models (CustomUser and Profile) located in different apps. I'm hoping someone can identify where I am going wrong here:

Here is my profiles/models.py --- you can see my user field attempting to create a OneToOne with with my users/models.py:

```
from django.db import models

from core.models import TimeStampedModel

class Profile(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField('users.CustomUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name      = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name       = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    bio             = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image           = models.URLField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.user.username
```

Here is my users/models.py:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, TimeStampedModel):
    username = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=255, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(db_index=True, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_provider = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    @property
    def token(self):
        return self._generate_jwt_token()

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username

    def _generate_jwt_token(self):
        dt = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=60)

        token = jwt.encode({
            'id': self.pk,
            'exp': int(dt.strftime('%s'))
        }, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithm='HS256')

        return token.decode('utf-8')
```

So the idea is that when I create a new user, a profile is automatically created as well. To do this, I am using a post_save signal in my users app:

users/signals.py:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from conduit.apps.profiles.models import Profile

from .models import User

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_related_profile(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance and created:
        instance.profile = Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

And finally an update to my users/**init**.py file:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class UsersAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'django.users'
    label = 'users'
    verbose_name = 'Users'

    def ready(self):
        import users.signals

default_app_config = 'django.users.UsersAppConfig'
```

That last update is something I am relatively unfamiliar with. I suspect this is where my problem is located.

I am able to resister a new user via an api call with no problem, however, when I test to see if a Profile object exists for that new user, I am left with the following error:

```
python manage.py shell

from users.models import CustomUser

u = CustomerUser.objects.last()

u
<CustomUser:testuser@gmail.com> --- everything works to this point

u.profile --- this is where it breaks down
```

I'm left with this error in shell:

```
users.models.CustomUser.profile.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: CustomUser has no profile.
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you show how you create your users (i.e. how was `u` created in your example above)? Also, I believe your `init.py` file should be named `__init__.py` instead (two underscores before and after). This is typical Python convention...

Comment: The __init__.py is not the issue. It looks like I had originally typed that, but the double underscores passed some unwanted markdown on my text. The 'u' object was created from my CustomUser model. You can see that imported during my shell session. Above that, you can see my actual CustomUser model. I left out the CustomerUserManager for the sake of brevity.

Comment: You did call the `save()` routine to create your user instance though, correct? If you used something like `bulk_create()`, the `save()` routine gets bypassed, which means your signals won't fire.

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Prior to extending the AbstractBaseUser in my CustomUser model, I defined a create_user and create_superuser function where I explicitly make a user.save() call before returning user. I'm investigating this more.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is in your signal method:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from conduit.apps.profiles.models import Profile

from .models import User # you have CustomUser but you are calling User

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_related_profile(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance and created: # you should only have created because you want this happen only when it is created
        instance.profile = Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Also, I see no need updating the users `init.py`.